# cell array of strings to matrix

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, cell-array

```
A = {'a','b','c','b','a',...}
```

`A` is a `<1X400>` cell array and I want to create a matrix from `A` such that if the cell is `a`, the matrix shows 1, if it is `b`, it shows as 2 in the matrix and 3 for `c`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Specific Case**

For a simple specific case as listed in the question, you can use [`char`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) to convert all the cell elements to characters and then subtract `96` from it, which is ascii equivalent of `'a'-1` -

```
A_numeric = char(A)-96
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A = 
    'a'    'b'    'c'    'b'    'a'
>> A_numeric = char(A)-96
A_numeric =
     1
     2
     3
     2
     1
```

---

**Generic Case**

For a generic substitution case, you need to do a bit more of work like so -

```
%// Inputs
A = {'correct','boss','cat','boss','correct','cat'}
newcellval = {'correct','cat','boss'}
newnumval = [8,2,5]

[unqcell,~,idx]  = unique(A,'stable')
[~,newcell_idx,unqcell_idx] = intersect(newcellval,unqcell,'stable')
A_numeric = newnumval(changem(idx,newcell_idx,unqcell_idx))
```

Sample input-output -

```
>> A,newcellval,newnumval
A = 
    'correct'    'boss'    'cat'    'boss'    'correct'    'cat'
newcellval = 
    'correct'    'cat'    'boss'
newnumval =
     8     2     5
>> A_numeric
A_numeric =
     8     5     2     5     8     2
```

Answer (score 2):

That's easy:

```
result = cell2mat(A)-'a'+1
```

---

For a *generic* association of *letters* to numbers 1,2,3...:

```
letters2numbers = 'abc'; %// 'a'->1, 'b'->2 etc.
[~, result] = ismember(cell2mat(A), letters2numbers)
```

---

For a *generic* association of *strings* to numbers 1,2,3...:

```
strings2numbers = {'hi', 'hello', 'hey', 'good morning', 'howdy'};
A = {'hello', 'hi', 'hello', 'howdy', 'bye'};
[~, result] = ismember(A, strings2numbers)
```

In this example,

```
result =
     2     1     2     5     0
```

Comment: works very nicely but what if the cell contains a "word" such as "correct"?

Comment: @chinkare_16 Think you can use `unique` in that case - `[~,~,out]  = unique(A,'stable')`. But, then what to map to what, you need to decide that.

Answer (score 1):

use a For Loop which iterate over A and convert character to number

```
for loop = 1:length(A)
  outMat(loop) = char(A(loop)) - 96
end
```

I hope it works.

Comment: `for` loop is not necessary.  This can be done vectorized.  See Divakar's answer.